# MySQL ID Increment Conundrum

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a mysql table with auto increment. I'm using an id as the primary key.

Here is the structure of the key::
    id  int(255)            No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT

This is how the increments have happened:

[image: for some reason SO wasn't accepting this question with this data. Admins please note]

As you can see xxxxxxxxYY series, only the YY numbers are incremented.

---

This is the insert statement.

```
$id = $this->get_next_id($this->get_last_id());
$q = 'INSERT INTO '.URL_TABLE.' (id, url, date, title, image, description) 
VALUES ("'.$id.'", "'.$url.'", NOW(), "'.$title.'", "'.$image.'", "'.$description.'")';
```

Comment: Do you have some trigger that changes the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO No. I simply add values to the table. Since it is set to auto-increment it should take care of the increment on its own.

Comment: If you make an `INSERT` with a higher number, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` will set itself to that new value.

Comment: Show your `INSERT` query.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I've updated my Q with the insert query.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I've updated my Q with the insert query.

Comment: Your problem is in `get_next_id`. why use an auto_increment (note the **auto**) when you do it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to give a new ID. Your column is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so it will increment automatically (hence the name).

Just insert like this, and let the database handle the increments:

```
$q = 'INSERT INTO '.URL_TABLE.' (url, date, title, image, description) 
VALUES ("'.$url.'", NOW(), "'.$title.'", "'.$image.'", "'.$description.'")';
```

(Just omit the `id` column altogether)

Comment: awesome! it worked.
Although I still don't understand, why it skipped all those numbers after xxxxx99?

Comment: As I said in the comments, the problem lies in `$this->get_next_id`. Without seeing that code, we can't tell.